# Conditional formatting rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking for similar topics but couldn't find a proper solution to my problem.

**Objectives:**
I have an excel sheet where I put the data regarding my job research:
-company, job position, application sent date,..., and finally the numbers of days passed between the application date and today's date.

I would like a macro that checks the number of days waited per position (value in column I) and conditionally applies a color to the entire line. This way I can have a good follow-up on my job research.

**Code used**

```
Sub outofdate()
Range("I4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
numrow = Selection.Rows.Count

For r = 4 To numrow
    c = Cells(r, 9).Value
    Select Case c
           Case Is = 7 < c < 10
           ColorIndex = 4
           Case Is = 10 < c < 15
           ColorIndex = 45
           Case Is = 15 < c < 21
           ColorIndex = 3

    End Select 'c

    With Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 9)).Select
        Selection.Interior.Color = ColorIndex
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

**Problem faced**
When I run the macro, the cells from range A4:I12 are all colored in black even though I don't put a color index that refers to black.

Thanks for you time, I've been trying to figure out what went wrong but my knowledge seems to stop here.

Comment: following on @pnuts comment - Select your Range, then Home on the Ribbon, then conditional formatting. There are several options to create the formats, even a formula option.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you want to do this with VBA, can't you do this easily with the build in conditional formatting options inside Excel?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes I know I could use conditional formatting using excel options, however I wanted to understand the logic behind it by doing it in VBA, just out of curiosity.

Comment: A note on the variable `ColorIndex`, I would use another name for that, since it's a specific word used in VBA (`Cells(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4`).  I tend to use `clrIndex` or something when setting that as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if the code for black is zero and your color variable was never changed from zero so it would give you the black color. Also the notation for the "Select Case" was not working properly.

[Sample for Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

```
Option Explicit

Sub outofdate()

    Dim rWorkRange As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim lColorIndex As Long
    Dim lValue As Long

    ' Set the range for the loop.
    Set rWorkRange = Range(Range("I4"), Range("I4").End(xlDown))

    ' Loop through the range.
    For Each r In rWorkRange

        lValue = r.Value

        ' Select each case, make sure that the else sets the
        ' lColorIndex variable to the default "0"
        Select Case lValue
            Case 7 To 10
                lColorIndex = 4
            Case 10 To 15
                lColorIndex = 45
            Case 15 To 21
                lColorIndex = 3
            Case Else
                lColorIndex = 0
        End Select

        ' Check for the "0" value (This is the black color)
        ' if the lColorIndex is zero then skip.
        If Not lColorIndex = 0 Then
            Cells(r.Row, 1).Resize(, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = lColorIndex
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Indeed it helped a lot ! thanks ! I understand now the logic, the only point I don't get is the "lValue = r.Value"

Comment: "lValue = r.Value" is used to the get the value of the cell in the loop

Comment: you are right, I am putting the value in a range in a variable for later checking.

Answer (score 0):

I have used if and else if instead of select case

```
    Sub outofdate()


    Dim numrow As Long

    numrow = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 4 To numrow
    c = Cells(r, 9).Value


    If c > 7 And c < 10 Then

         Cells(r, 9).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    ElseIf c > 10 And c < 15 Then

          Cells(r, 9).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 45

    ElseIf c > 15 And c < 21 Then

        Cells(r, 9).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    End If

   Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed it worked but it was only highlighting the cell and not the entire line.

Comment: @M.O - easy fix, just change the lines ending with `.ColorIndex` to `Cells(r,9).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex` (add the `EntireRow` bit).  Then it'll highlight the whole line!

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks. I have made changes in the solution.

Comment: @M.O now check the answer